# CakePHP 2.5.2 Themeing and theme.ctp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I've created a simple application that is about to be vastly expanded upon and get a bit out of hand if I don't get the theme sorted out early as I need to start working with tinyMCE.

I created my theme in app/View/Themed/Default and added the following into my app controller

```
public $theme = 'Default';
```

Something seems to be working because cakePHP is not rendering my views and is giving me the following errors.

> Error: The view for {controller name}Controller::add() was not found.
>
> Error: Confirm you have created the file:
>   /home/cake/public_html/app/View/Themed/Default/{controller}/theme.ctp

I've been reading through the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html) and nowhere in there does it tell me that I need to create a folder for every controller and add a theme.ctp file inside. so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what needs to go into this theme.ctp file.

If I add the Controller folder, and a blank them.ctp file, the view is not rendered. So I am assuming something vital is required here.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem.

Further down the page from legacy code that was ported across, the following code was sitting at the bottom of the page.

**AppController.php**

```
function beforeRender() {
    $this->view = "Theme";
    $this->theme = "default";
}
```

So it was being forced into rendering a view that did not exist.